# Download Files from BIM 360 Without Authorization

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am integrating between Design automation and BIM 360 API in autodesk forge

1. I call step 7 Design automation
   https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/

```
{
        "activityId": "YOUR_NICKNAME.DeleteWallsActivity+test",
        "arguments": {
          "rvtFile": {
            "url": "SIGNED_URL_TO_INPUT_FILE",
            "pathInZip": "PATH_TO_RVT_FILE_WITHIN_ZIP_FILE"
          },
          "result": {
            "verb": "put",
            "url": "SIGNED_URL_TO_RESULT"
          }
        }
      }'
```

The param rvtFile.(url), i binding link download file by step 5 in Bim 360 Document
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/download-document/

```
{
    "activityId": "cbbdemo.DemoTestingActivity43+test",
    "arguments": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/11d42fe8-7612-4120-ad7d-a688e49143a1.rvt",
            "localName": "testing.rvt",
        },
        "params": {
            "url": "data:application/json,{'action' : 'generate','scaffoldName' : 'SM0918', 'space' : 300,'isGenFront' : true,'data' : ['138763','138533']}"
        },
        "result": {
            "verb": "put",                            
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/fbe64c4f-1073-49a7-810b-95658e51b361?region=US"
        }
    }
}
```

But when download file revit by API Bim 360 is failed because need token Authorization
So is there a way to download files from bim 360 without tokens?

Comment: You can't download file from BIM360 without authorisation token. You must use a signed url for your Revit file. This is described in [Task 6 - Prepare Cloud Storage](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot call the OSS API https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/11d42fe8-7612-4120-ad7d-a688e49143a1.rvt without passing an access token.

The solution is to use a Signed URL to download the file, but since you're not the owner of the bucket `wip.dm.prod`. It's owned by BIM360 or ACC service itself. So you cannot create Signed URLs for objects stored on the `wip.dm.prod` bucket. So, at this moment, please pass a valid access token like the one below:

```json
{
    "activityId": "cbbdemo.DemoTestingActivity43+test",
    "arguments": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/11d42fe8-7612-4120-ad7d-a688e49143a1.rvt",
            "localName": "testing.rvt",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Bearer {{Bearer}}",
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"  
            }
        },
        "params": {
            "url": "data:application/json,{'action' : 'generate','scaffoldName' : 'SM0918', 'space' : 300,'isGenFront' : true,'data' : ['138763','138533']}"
        },
        "result": {
            "verb": "put",                            
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/fbe64c4f-1073-49a7-810b-95658e51b361?region=US"
        }
    }
}
```